# How to open up live camera view of wikitude-phonegap

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, wikitude

Although I have read all [documents](http://developer.wikitude.com/documentation/phonegap) of wikitude (phonegap plugin for iOS), i still couldn't understand how to open up live camera view. In the example project of wikitude, camera view shows up by native code and there is no example project for phonegap plugin at all.

In my project, i have installed wikitude plugin properly as shown [here](http://developer.wikitude.com/documentation/phonegap). At the page which is supposed to show augmented reality view, i have included necessary .js files such as  WikitudePlugin.js,  ade.js and architect://architect.js however the page shows only html view like normal page. What am i supposed to do to turn this page out to live camera view?

Answer (score 0):

You should not include architect://architect.js together with the WiktiudePlugin.js.

Basically the AR html, js, css content is separated from your usual phonegap code. Just add the augmented reality content (that includes architect.js) as assets.

Inside your phonegap application call 
WikitudePlugin.loadARchitectWorld(successCallback, errorCallback, "path/to/your/world")

This will open the ar content at "path/to/your/world" inside the Wiktiude SDK. The Wikitude SDK than displays the camera live view.

Again keep in mind that the augmented reality content is conceptional different to the phonegap application.

Disclaimer: I work for Wikitude.